# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while running spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

Getting below error while running a spring boot application. Can anybody help?

**Application Class**

```
package com.dell.cns.services.esb.heartbeat.satcps;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.dell.cns.services.esb")
public class CnsServicesHeartBeatSatcpsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CnsServicesHeartBeatSatcpsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Error Message**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext;
    at com.dell.cns.services.esb.heartbeat.satcps.CnsServicesHeartBeatSatcpsApplication.main(CnsServicesHeartBeatSatcpsApplication.java:12)
```

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml file . looks like you have two versions of the same (spring) dependency.

Comment: You are right that was the issue. Thanks

Comment: which duplicate dependency was it?

Comment: I'm getting the same exception. Could someone help pls.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **Intellij IDEA**, do the following:
**Menu -> File -> invalidate cache/restart**

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and fixed it by right-clicking on project->Maven->Update project. The App was then up and running on Tomcat server.

Answer (score 1):

After updating to Java 11 , SpringBoot applications throw many errors.
I updated Spring boot version to 2.4.0 and made the changes in main method as below:

ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args);

After building and trying to run the application again throws the error like below

"NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run"

and fixed it by Right click on project -> Maven -> Update maven project

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error related to Spring Boot and Maven 3.8.* build tool. The solution in my case is to change Maven home path (In ItennliJ IDEA Build Tools) to **Bundled (Maven 3)**