# Error during spring-boot app launch from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

I'm trying to launch my spring-boot app from eclipse, doing the following

> Right-click on the project -> Run As ->Spring Boot App

but it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext;
    at it.ivu.ratp.server.AppServer.main(AppServer.java:29)
```

I've tried different versions of the eclipse, but every time the same error. Even if the same app is launching without problems from cmd using maven

> mvn spring-boot: run

Thank you in advance

AppServer class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({ "it" })
@EnableJms
public class AppServer {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(AppServer.class, args);
}

@Qualifier("itDataSource")
@Autowired
private DataSource itDatasource;

@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the message converter
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    // You could still override some of Boot's default if necessary.
    return factory;
}

@Bean
// Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:db/liquibase-changelog.xml");

    liquibase.setDataSource(ivuDatasource);
    return liquibase;
}
```

}

Comment: can you show class `AppServer.java` ?

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67733618/421195

Comment: @paulsm4 i've tried this yet

Comment: ADDITIONAL SUGGESTIONS: 1) Try `Eclipse > Project > Maven > Update project` 2) try running `mvn spring-boot: run` from Eclipse (invoke the "maven" part of your project, rather "run as" the "project root"), 3) Ensure your command line JRE (the one that works) matches your Eclipse JRE, 4) Double-check your Eclipse CLASSPATHs